# Why the carousel doesn't automatically change - PHP

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4

I've created simple page where you can add images to database.
 Here is my code, where i pull images to website: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyYeE.png)

in DevTools i can see that all images are pulled correctly:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93Vof.png)

But when i click next/previous
website is reloading, but picture is still the same, and URL is changed:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMcuu.png)

Do you have any idea why?
I even add JS script to add intervals to this carousel but it's still doesn't work.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem about javascript library. it is not loading. You need to add full code to test it.